# Adding Google Satellite imagery to QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have added Google Satellite in QGIS but it is not displaying and I am getting the following message:

> network request to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) timed out, any data received is likely incomplete. Please check the message log for further info'

When I go to the message log it's just the link with timed out at the end.

Have tried to change the CRS of the layer to WGS 84 /UTM zone 36s EPSG:32736 as I am from Malawi

Comment: How did you try adding the Google Satellite imagery?

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/klakar/QGIS_resources/master/collections/Geosupportsystem/python/qgis_basemaps.py

Answer (score 2):

You can add Google Layers as XYZ tiles.

Right-click on 'XYZ tiles' and click on 'New Connection'
Paste the following URLs into the field.
[image]

NAME: GE Hybrid

URL: [http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}](http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&hl=en&x=%7Bx%7D&y=%7By%7D&z=%7Bz%7D)

NAME: GE Roadmap

URL: [http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}](http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&hl=en&x=%7Bx%7D&y=%7By%7D&z=%7Bz%7D)

NAME: GE Terrain

URL: [http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=p&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}](http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=p&hl=en&x=%7Bx%7D&y=%7By%7D&z=%7Bz%7D)

NAME: GE Altered roadmap

URL: [http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=r&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}](http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=r&hl=en&x=%7Bx%7D&y=%7By%7D&z=%7Bz%7D)

NAME: GE Satellite only

URL: [http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}](http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&hl=en&x=%7Bx%7D&y=%7By%7D&z=%7Bz%7D)

NAME: GE Terrain only

URL: [http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=t&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}](http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=t&hl=en&x=%7Bx%7D&y=%7By%7D&z=%7Bz%7D)

Layers will be added. If you double-click the layer, the corresponding layer is added as a raster layer to the QGIS canvas.